# Copy a file from local machine to docker container

Tags: docker, hadoop

I am following [this](https://clubhouse.io/developer-how-to/how-to-set-up-a-hadoop-cluster-in-docker/) example:

I find the `namenode` as follows:

```
(dash_apps_36) idf@ubvm:~/Documents/docker-hadoop$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS                                            NAMES
2ce71013488f        bde2020/hadoop-resourcemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8   "/entrypoint.sh /run\u2026"   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes (healthy)      8088/tcp                                         resourcemanager
7fc72b887e23        bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8          "/entrypoint.sh /run\u2026"   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes (healthy)      0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9870->9870/tcp   namenode
9c3f8c435b87        bde2020/hadoop-nodemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8       "/entrypoint.sh /run\u2026"   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes (healthy)      8042/tcp                                         nodemanager
4d57c5bf2f9e        bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8          "/entrypoint.sh /run\u2026"   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes (healthy)      9864/tcp                                         datanode
c7eef33905e8        bde2020/hadoop-historyserver:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8     "/entrypoint.sh /run\u2026"   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes (healthy)      8188/tcp                                         historyserver
2b1144867924        redis                                                    "docker-entrypoint.s\u2026"   6 days ago          Exited (137) 6 days ago                                                       serene_keldysh
9d9463166b63        redis                                                    "docker-entrypoint.s\u2026"   6 days ago          Created                                                                       eloquent_merkle
47d6488e29bf        redis:alpine                                             "docker-entrypoint.s\u2026"   4 weeks ago         Exited (137) 4 weeks ago                                                      wikipedia-playground_redis_1
be5ea0df0401        mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest               "/opt/mssql/bin/perm\u2026"   18 months ago       Exited (255) 18 months ago   0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp                           mssql
```

Using `7fc72b887e23` as the ID of the `namenode`, when I get to the command

```
$ docker cp ../hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1-sources.jar cb0c13085cd3:hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1-sources.jar
```

I get an error:

```
$: command not found
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `$` at the beginning. That's what `$: command not found` means. Easy to miss when copy pasting code

```
docker cp ../hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1-sources.jar cb0c13085cd3:hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1-sources.jar
```

Comment: Nah, done the same hundred times. Not sure why code posted online most of the time makes the `$` symbol part of it! Like "copy paste this into the terminal" is enough and just skip the `$` in the code section :=)

Comment: Most commonly, in notation, `$` is used to designate user-mode and `#` is used to specify root-mode